# Was able to use proprietary ATI driver before, now on clean install I don't have that option

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, hardware, fglrx

I am running 12.04LTS, and I just formatted.  Prior to the format, I was using the ATI proprietary driver through "additional drivers".  I have two ATI radeons that are crossfired.   Now, when I do go to additional drivers, it can't find any drivers.

I attempted the fglrx install through https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI, but it ended badly.

I just did a clean swipe again and would like to know where to go from here. My working previous install was fully updated as of yesterday. (18th of March, 2013)

Comment: Please leave a comment telling us the model number of your two crossfired ATI Radeons.

Comment: radeon hd3850's

Comment: Are you sure that you downloaded the correct driver for your system? The download link to the correct driver for your graphics card is found [here](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/legacy/Pages/legacy-radeon_linux.aspx)

Comment: huh, indeed, it has a different file name than the file I downloaded before.  it has legacy, where as the 13.1 i downloaded from AMD's site before lacked that term.  i hope that works!  Will let you know.  Thanks.

Comment: well, that kind of worked.  it ran flawlessly until  `DKMS part of installation failed.  Please refer to /usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log for details` .  that was the only error.

Comment: Building module:
cleaning build area....
cd /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.97.100.7/build; sh make.sh --nohints --uname_r=3.5.0-26-generic --norootcheck.....(bad exit status: 1)
[Error] Kernel Module : Failed to build fglrx-8.97.100.7 with DKMS
[Error] Kernel Module : Removing fglrx-8.97.100.7 from DKMS

Comment: ok, k3.5 isn't supported on that driver.  I'm an idiot.  will try again after rollback.  thanks,.\

Comment: sure enough, it was the kernel version.